# Activities based on weather condition

Tags: views, 8

I am looking for a way to implement a "show me activities based on weather-condition" feature.

A page-user will see a weather forecast for today and the three following days with two appropriate activities underneath each.

The activities custom-post-types still exist and offer the season, weather-condition and temperature they fit best. 
The actual weather conditions will come from openweathermap.
The main problem I have atm is how to filter the specific activities depending on the weather-condition. How can I tell views the specific logic I need?

Any hint how to practically achieve this?

Emanuel

Comment: You could create a view with a contextual filter and use [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x) to provide the argument to your view.